# VB.NET: Redireccionar a página externa en nueva pestaña

Tags: vb.net

Necesito redireccionar a una página externa de la mía, resulta que la URL la obtengo a través de una API con VB.NET y debo abrir una nueva pestaña con esa URL, la cual siempre va cambiando, pero el problema es que el navegador me bloquea la nueva pestaña y necesito evitar eso. 
Me pueden ayudar? por favor

Comment: si el navegador te la bloquea, es cuestión de configurar el navegador correctamente supongo. De todas formas, cómo abres la url en una nueva pestaña? con un target=_blank en un tag 'a'?

Comment: No quiero depender de eso, porque la página la utilizan miles de usuarios y hay veces que el bloqueo pasa desapercibido o simplemente no saben como quitar dicho bloqueo